# Поставка release в MSVC++

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

Как сделать релиз программы DirectX в MSVC++, для запуска на других компьютерах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно включить в msi-пакет распространяемый пакет установки DirectX и запустить его на установку как пользовательское действие (Custom Action). Это делается в Visual Studio в проекте Setup. Подробнее про установку DirectX (на английском): [DirectX Installation for Game Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416805(v=VS.85).aspx).